# Reading JSON object in Struts Action class

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

Let me explain what is the current state and then i will mention the problem.

From my jsp page i am making a call to Struts 2 Action, through `$getJSON` method of `jQuery` in javascript.

Here is the code :

```
var a = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};
var b = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};
var c = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};

var users = [a,b,c];

   $.getJSON
      (
        "createUser.action",
        {
            "users":users+""
        },
        function (data){
//          alert(data.status);
            if(data.status == "SUCCESS"){
                location.reload();              
            }else{
                alert("Creating User Failed");
            }   
        }
    );
```

I want to read the json object sent through request, in my Struts Action class.
Here's my Action class :

```
public class ProcessUser extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.request = servletRequest;
}

public String execute() {


    String data = request.getParameter("users");

    System.out.println("data is :"+data);


    //data = "{\"users\":"+data+"}";

    System.out.println("data is :"+data);


    //data = "{\n  \"users\": [\n    {\n      \"id\": \"ddsa\",\n      \"firstName\": \"dasda\",\n      \"lastName\": \"asaas\",\n      \"email\": \"dasdds\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"id\": \"ddsa\",\n      \"firstName\": \"dasda\",\n      \"lastName\": \"asaas\",\n      \"email\": \"dasdds\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";

    try {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(data);

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)json.get("users");

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(0);

        System.out.println("id:"+jsonObject.get("firstName"));
        /*
        System.out.println("name=" + json.get("users[id"));
        System.out.println("width=" + json.get("users.firstName"));*/
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 return SUCCESS;
 }
```

I get an exception stacktrace like this :

```
Unexpected character (o) at position 1.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
```

Can you please help me solving this problem. How can i read that json object.

Comment: JSONArray json = (JSONArray)new JSONParser().parse(data);
Instead of typecasting as JSONObject, type cast it to JSONArray,

Comment: hey, Vijay, it throws same exception. Even i tried commenting `data = "{\"users\":"+data+"}";`, but results same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for declaring the arrays

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON( input );
```

where input is the JSON string

Answer (score 0):

After many iterations i found out the solution fro the problem.

While sending the request from JavaScript i have to use `JSON.stringify(data)`, i.e

```
var a = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};
var b = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};
var c = {"id":"ddsa","firstName":"dasda","lastName":"asaas","email":"dasdds"};

var users = [a,b,c];

$.getJSON
  (
    "createUser.action",
    {
        "users":JSON.stringify(users)
    },
    function (data){
//          alert(data.status);
        if(data.status == "SUCCESS"){
            location.reload();              
        }else{
            alert("Creating User Failed");
        }   
    }
);
```

And in struts Action class i used,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(data);
```

Then iterated this array and got `JOSNObject` to fetch all the property values, i.e

```
JOSNObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
```

Thanks for your support.